# How to get only "p" tags inside "small single" article?

Tags: scala, selenium

I need to get all p tags (text inside them) inside article.

- [Website code area screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ey73.png)

Into this (after Try {...} is free to edit):

```
var d2 = ""; Try { d2 = *(driver.findElements(By.tagName("p"))).head.getText }
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current solution?

Comment: @Prophet i can get only one p tag, but i need to take them all (check screenshot pls), it doesnt work via xpath, cz it changing page to page (cssSelector too), one webpage can contais 10 p tags, another 1 p, and etc.

Comment: @AlexanderBondarenko You only have a single variable to populate. How do you want the data to look when you're done? A List of Strings? A single concatenated String? Something else?

Comment: And is this a Java or a Scala question?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax you are using here, what I know is that `driver.findElements` returns a `List` of `WebElement`s. What you have to do here is to iterate over that list and extract text from each `WebElement` object.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley scala

Comment: @Prophet yeah, answer below is helped, it get only first p tag, but i need them all XD

Comment: I understand, however I don't know how to do that in scala. If it can help I can give you Java solution

Comment: @Im junior in scala, but could you please?) I will try it

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  var d2 = ""; 
  Try { d2 = *(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//article[@class='small single']//p"))).head.getText }
  ```
- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  var d2 = ""; 
  Try { d2 = *(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("article.small.single p"))).head.getText }
  ```

Comment: it works, but it takes only first p, but i need all, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid mutability wherever possible in Scala. Using the selector from [undetected Selenium's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71602531/how-to-get-only-p-tags-inside-small-single-article/71602578#71602578):

```scala
import scala.collection.JavaConverters

val javaData = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("article.small.single p"))

val data: Seq[String] = JavaConverters.asScalaBufferConverter(javaData)
  .asScala
  .map(element => element.getText)
```

`driver.findElements` returns a Java List, so we need to convert it into a Scala collection before being able to use `.map` over it.